# collect function on clobs

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to select several clobs as a nested table.

```
create table t (vc_val varchar2(100), clob_val clob);
create type varchar_t as table of varchar2(100);
create type clob_t as table of clob;
```

Following query works fine:

```
select cast(collect(vc_val) as varchar_t) from t;
```

And following fails, why?

```
select cast(collect(clob_val) as clob_t) from t;
```

Link to this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b01e7/3

Can someone explain me why second query fails?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `CAST` doesn't support LOB types.

You can read about this in Oracle's Documentation: [CAST Function In Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613)

Using your test data from [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b01e7/3), `CAST` can convert a `CLOB` to a `VARCHAR2`:

```
SELECT CAST(clob_val AS VARCHAR2(100)) FROM t;
```

Result:

```
CAST(CLOB_VALASVARCHAR2(100))
-----------------------------
clob1
clob2
```

But we can't do it the other way around, the `CLOBs` are just not supported:

```
SELECT CAST(vc_val AS CLOB) FROM t;
```

```
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_clob_tab as table of clob;

declare
    l_clob_tab t_clob_tab;
begin
    -- collect some data as clobs into a nested table
    select
    cast(multiset(
        select to_clob(object_name)
        from dba_objects
        where rownum <= 10)
    as t_clob_tab)
    into l_clob_tab
    from dual;

    -- show the data
    for i in 1 .. l_clob_tab.count
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Clob' || i || ' Value is: ' || l_clob_tab(i));
    end loop;

end;
```

Output:

```
Clob1 Value is: C_OBJ#
Clob2 Value is: I_OBJ#
Clob3 Value is: TAB$
Clob4 Value is: CLU$
Clob5 Value is: C_TS#
Clob6 Value is: I_TS#
Clob7 Value is: C_FILE#_BLOCK#
Clob8 Value is: I_FILE#_BLOCK#
Clob9 Value is: C_USER#
Clob10 Value is: I_USER#
```

As for the [CAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm#SQLRF51258) function support for LOB types:

> CAST does not directly support any of the LOB data types. When you use
>   CAST to convert a CLOB value into a character data type or a BLOB
>   value into the RAW data type, the database implicitly converts the LOB
>   value to character or raw data and then explicitly casts the resulting
>   value into the target data type. If the resulting value is larger than
>   the target type, then the database returns an error.

This seems to refer to converting from a CLOB -> Varchar.  But if you already have Clobs, you should be able to put them into a collection (a nested table in this case).

I typically use CAST + MULTISET instead of COLLECT, I think its easier and less fussy.  I think your problem is with COLLECT + CAST here, not CAST itself (similar issue with NUMBER precisions).

EDIT:
I removed any suggestion of using Collect function, although I could use it without error in a simple select, I could not use it in pl/sql.  Also, in addition to the CAST + MULTISET option above (SQL or pl/sql), you can (in pl/sql anyway) simply do:

```
select clob_col
bulk collect into l_clob_tab
from t;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can't use `COLLECT` with a `CLOB` parameter, it throws `00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"` error. At least it doesn't work for me... +1 for the `MULTISET` approach.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Thanks for that. I can use COLLECT with a CLOB (select collect(clob_val) from t), but Oracle doesn't like CAST + COLLECT with a CLOB.  Not sure why to be honest, but I've had other issues with CAST + COLLECT, so I avoid it and use multiset.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I have one of the newest 11g releases... wondering why collect doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I'm just running the collect sql in Toad, and it returns a dataset type (does NOT throw an error).  However, I have not tried using it in PL/SQL.  My experience with Collect has been buggy (or maybe I should say weird ;), I swear I had some SQL using collect that would shutdown my connection to Oracle (consistently), wish I still had that one to post.  Anyway, my 2 cents is to use Cast + Multiset and avoid collect.